# I design a class and base pointer is created but it give error when I try to access a derived function through base pointer

Tags: c++, oop

I create a base pointer and pass the address of the derived object to it. But an error displayed when I tried to access a function named `fun()` through that pointer. Why does this code give errors?

```cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Base
{
    public:
    virtual void fun ()
    {
        cout << "Base::fun()"<< endl;
    }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
    public:
    virtual void fun ( int x )
    {
        cout << "Derived::fun(), x = " << x << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Derived d1;
    Base *bp = &d1;
    bp->fun(5);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think you should add the error message to the question. Use the edit link.

Comment: The base class does not have a function named `f` that takes an argument.

Comment: `override` keyword helps spotting such issues...

Answer (score 0):

Because in your base class you only have a function fun(). It is only in your derived class that you have fun(int). You fun(int) is not overriding the fun() in the base class, rather it is creating a new function entirely - function signature is not only the name but the name and the parameters.

Since you are accessing the object through a base pointer, you can't access fun(int) but fun().